# Remove Item From Listview using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I have a strange problem in my `ListView` and I don't understand why it happens.

In my `checklist` when I select 3 or more items only last and first Item are deleted the second item is not deleted. It just remains selected and I need to click this post button again.

> SendDataFragment Activity

```
   btn_DataSend=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.trn_post_btn);
    btn_DataSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

            //get All info like custID, mStatus mTrnNo mCustID mCustName
            List<customerInfo> stateList = adapter.mCategories;

            for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
            {
                customerInfo state = stateList.get(i);
                if(state.ismStatus())
                {
                    //postData(state.getmTrnNo());
                    int c = i;
                    dbManager.delete_ShipmentDetails(state.getmCustID());
                    stateList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).sho();
        }
    });
```

> DBManager

```
 public void delete_ShipmentDetails(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ DatabaseHelper.TBL_OE_SHIPMENT_H +" WHERE " +DatabaseHelper.OE_SHIPMENT_H_CUSTID+"="+id);
}
```

> My App screen-shots are:

[image: Before Remove Item]
[image: After Remove Item]

Comment: I would suggest you debug and check if it goes through `if(state.ismStatus())` condition.

Comment: The first issue that I can see with your code is that you are looping through a list and deleting items from it.  I would recommend going through this list in reverse order.

Comment: yes,  I have debug it This Condition return the a true or false it actually define which item I was selected like it return false when i = 0 and true for i = 1, 2, 3 since i was select those items on my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **loop** in reverse order

```
 for(int i = stateList.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        customerInfo state = stateList.get(i);
        if(state.ismStatus())
        {
            //postData(state.getmTrnNo());
            int c = i;
            dbManager.delete_ShipmentDetails(state.getmCustID());
            stateList.remove(i);
            notifyItemRemoved(i);
        }
     }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you I got it .. Thanks everyOne

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are looping through a list whilst changing the length of it.

There are several methods to solve this problem, either loop through the list backwards, use an iterator or save the deletions until the end.  In order to change the loop to use an iterator the following should work as expected:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = stateList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    customerInfo state = it.next();
    if(state.ismStatus()) {
        dbManager.delete_ShipmentDetails(state.getmCustID());
        it.remove();
    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I Get It Clearly I have also made another Way Just Change here like

```
       for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
                    {
                        customerInfo state = stateList.get(i);
                        if(state.ismStatus())
                        {
                            postData(state.getmTrnNo());
                            dbManager.delete_ShipmentDetails(state.getmCustID());
                            stateList.remove(i);
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```